# Javascript to show divs depend on mobile type

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, iphone

iam trying to do that by javascript : 1- check the mobile type if ANDROID show ANDROID_USERS div if IPHONE show IOS_USERS div 
2- show the above div ONEC ONLY ONE TIME IN THE FIRST VISIT <-- this work successfully

but check the mobile type its not working so i need to know if i do it in the right way i use

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf

to test the code if work on iphone and android

what i need to know is if i check the mobile type in right way or not ?

```
<head>
    <style>
            #IOS_USERS {
                display: block;
                display:none;
            }

            #ANDROID_USERS {
                display: block;
                display:none;
            }

    </style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//check mobile type
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }

};

            function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
            }


            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i].trim();
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
                return "";
            }

            function MarkVisited() {
                setCookie("visited", "visited", 10)
            }

            function ClearCookie(cname) {
                setCookie(cname, "", 1)
            }



            $(document).ready(function() {

                 if (getCookie('visited') == "" && isMobile.iOS()) {
                    $('#ANDROID_USERS').hide();
                    $('#IOS_USERS').show();
                }
                else if (getCookie('visited') == "" && isMobile.Android()) {
                    $('#ANDROID_USERS').show();
                    $('#IOS_USERS').hide();
                }
                MarkVisited();
            });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="IOS_USERS">
         IOS 
        </div>
        <div id="ANDROID_USERS">
         ANDROID 
        </div>
        <button id="ClearCookie" onClick="ClearCookie('visited')">Clear Cookie</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fit your website with most device,browser,etc..., I will recommend you to use http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html... It responsive and it will automatically fit the site with any device, but you have to follow some of their instruction ,how to do the layout design, grid, etc. It will save lot of your time on creating separate UI for each device. Hope this will help for you. :)

Comment: i need to make sure that the script when i use i phone its show the IOS_USERS div so i want to know if //check mobile type 
working well or not 
if you look at the script its on right way ?